# ASP.NET website translation

Tags: asp.net, url, translation

I want to translate my ASP.NET website, just like microsoft does.
I want the urls to have /en-EN/ or /de-DE/
the problem is that my urls ar already routed URLs

How can I do this?

I found this http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/26/Translating-routes-(ASPNET-MVC-and-Webforms).aspx
but I don't want to translate all the urls and this method seems to me too complex, with Views and Controllers.

I need mysite.com/en-EN/routedpage or mysite.com/de-DE/routedpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above example is for mvc, is your website in mvc?. You need to setup your website for culture specific setting, here is an article how to do that

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=3477182

Also for further reading

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7998/Creating-multilingual-websites-Part-1
and
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8073/Create-multilingual-web-pages-very-easily

its very easy to setup

Comment: it's not MVC, but I think I can mix MVC with normal ASP.NET.  I know how to translate with the resources, the only problem is how to make the URLs, since I already have routed urls.

Comment: The urls would be automatic, try running this on a different os, say a french or german and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

This is an important problem. You want the URL to have the language encoded in it for both SEO and usability purposes.

Two common solutions are:

1) Change the domain.  fr.example.com or de.example.com. Then the routes don't need to be changed.

2) Use the # for the language code. Search engines nowadays will observe this. So, then you'd have www.example.com/#de or www.example.com/#fr

You can implement both of these solutions with www.SiteTran.com by simply pasting our javascript into your page and setting the sitetran_url_type variable to either:

`var sitetran_url_type = 'sub.domain';`

or

`var sitetran_url_type = 'hash';`

SiteTran is 100% free and is my company.